# Displaying JSON event data from API in mattlewis92 angular-calendar

Tags: angular, calendar

I'm using https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-calendar in my current project and can't manage to display my JSON events with it. API data is fetched correctly as the browser is able to display my events as list with:

```
<li *ngFor="let event of events">
    {{event.title}} {{event.start}}
</li>
```

But angular-calendar doesn't.

This is the relevant code, maybe someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Service:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response } from '@angular/http';
@Injectable()

export class CalendarService {

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getAll() {
        return this.http.get('/events').map((response: Response) => response.json());
    } 
}
```

Component:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CalendarEvent } from 'angular-calendar';
import { CalendarService } from '../../../_services/calendar.service';

declare var $: any;


@Component({
    selector: 'app-calendar',
    templateUrl: './cal-overview.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./cal-overview.component.scss']
})

export class CalendarOverviewComponent {
    view = 'month';
    viewDate: Date = new Date();
    clickedDate: Date;
    events: CalendarEvent[] = [];

    constructor(private calendarService: CalendarService) {
        this.loadAllEvents();
    }
    private loadAllEvents() {
        this.calendarService.getAll().subscribe(
            events => {
                this.events = events;
            });
    }
    eventClicked({ event }: { event: CalendarEvent }): void {
        console.log('Event clicked', event);
    }
}
```

HTML Template:

```html
<app-calendar-header
            [(view)]="view"
            [(viewDate)]="viewDate">
 </app-calendar-header>
        <div class="alert alert-info">
            Click on a day on the view.
            <strong *ngIf="clickedDate">You clicked on this day: {{ clickedDate | date:'medium' }}</strong>
        </div>
        <div [ngSwitch]="view">
            <mwl-calendar-month-view
                *ngSwitchCase="'month'"
                [viewDate]="viewDate"
                [events]="events"
                [activeDayIsOpen]="true"
                (eventClicked)="eventClicked($event)"
                (dayClicked)="clickedDate = $event.day.date">
            </mwl-calendar-month-view>
            <mwl-calendar-week-view
                *ngSwitchCase="'week'"
                [viewDate]="viewDate"
                [events]="events"
                (eventClicked)="eventClicked($event)">
            </mwl-calendar-week-view>
            <mwl-calendar-day-view
                *ngSwitchCase="'day'"
                [viewDate]="viewDate"
                [events]="events"
                (eventClicked)="eventClicked($event)">
            </mwl-calendar-day-view>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it by checking the async demo:

https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-calendar/tree/master/demos/demo-modules/async-events

Be sure not to subscribe to the returned Observable coming from your API/Service. Just use .map according to your data structure and pass the Observable directly to your template and then use it with "async".